# Bypass dialer to make a call with pre-defined phone number

Tags: android, permissions

I need to figure out how to harness the power of the `CALL_PRIVILEGED` Permission in my app.

The basic layout is that when I activate the code it just goes to the Dialer with the number preloaded.

How do i bypass the dialer and just make the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your app to make a direct call? 
Take a look at `Intent.ACTION_CALL`  (ACTION_DAIL will show the number before calling).

EDIT: ACTION_CALL won't call emergency numbers.

Actually this changed from version to version of Android, so it could be that it works with 2.1 but not with 4.0.

Wolfen

Comment: Right, its giving me action Dial... Wont go near Action Call.

Comment: String numString = "tel:555123456".toString().trim();
  Intent callIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(numString)); Does not work? Whats your build target?

Comment: I got it fixed! Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @linuxrox please provide a hint of your solution.